# Why is my loop printing ints and not the strings

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I must be missing something basic here... (I'm new to coding). My code presents the user with a list of 20 names, ones at a time, the user then selects 'y' or 'n' if they like that name. The names are randomly generated from a list of 100. I then need that list of names (the 20 randomly generated names), to be presented to a second user, to also select 'y' or 'n' to them.

I have added the names that user 1 receives to a new empty list (new_boy_list), I now want to iterate through that list of names for the second user. Thing is, I get ints (0-19) instead of the list of names. What am I doing wrong? Here is the code... hopefully you can see what you need from it.

```
def user2_start():
print(f"{user2} it's now your turn... get ready..." + "\n")
# my_list = len(new_boy_list)
for name in range(20):
    print(name)
    user2_answer = input("y/n: ")
    if user2_answer == 'y':
        boy_list_2.append(name)
    print(boy_list_2)
```

Comment: You have `for name in range(20)`. A range is a sequence of numbers. So `name` is a number. Your code does not even reference a list of names.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't appear to have, or generate, a list of names (unless that's being done in code you haven't shown us). Also, as indicated in the comments, `name` actually contains a number - it isn't actually taking a string from a list of names.

What you'll want to do is load a list of names somehow, [shuffle it](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_random_shuffle.asp), and take the first 20. (You can use your existing `name` variable for that - just use it as an index into the list. You might want to rename the variable to a less misleading name, though, since it itself isn't actually a name).

You can load the list of names a number of ways. One way would be to have a text file that contains a name on each line and then read them in one line at a time into a list. You could also hardcode it, but that's probably not the best approach because it clutters up your code and you'd have to modify the code itself if you ever wanted to change the list - it's usually better to separate your code and data as much as possible.

There are more advanced approaches, such as retrieving them from a web service or database, but those are probably overkill for this.